# Spring boot and vuejs web app implementation approach

Tags: spring, rest, web, vue.js

I wrote a spring boot application and I want to use Vuejs for the front-end. I found online two ways to do this:

1 - store my html+vuejs in the resources/folder and use Thymeleaf and a controller to serve them.

2 - expose my spring rest-controllers and have my Vuejs application running separately and accessing the rest-api.

My question is: what is the difference between both approaches? and what approach is the most common?

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches are equivalent it's just a question of choice.

With thymeleaf you work with HTML/CSS/JS in and old fashioned way : you write your HTML, your CSS (or use your prefered css framework) and probably use jQuery as you know how to use it.

With VueJS things are a little complicated at first. You should learn a standart like ECMAScript (which will compile in to JavaScript with the help of Babel), the integration with your favorite css framework will be a litlle more complicated and the use of plugins is very different than you would do it with jQuery.

So it depends, if you want to grow as developer, learn some fun things and be "on top" you should take a look on VueJS but if you just need to "send something fast to production" you should make it with thymeleaf.

**But let me underline that you can make everything you want with both approaches.**